# Why doesn't the separator from IFS work for array expansion?

Tags: bash, array

I want to limit the change to the separator only to the following echo command not to the shell:

```
$ myarr=(1 2 3)

$ echo $( IFS="|"; echo "${myarr[@]}" )
1 2 3
```

Why doesn't the separator work for array expansion? Thanks.

Comment: According to `man bash`, "`${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value  of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable, and `${name[@]}` expands each element of name to a separate  word."

Comment: To encapsulate the answers: using `*` expands to a single string; using `@` expands to individual elements. But for both, **only when the expansion is quoted**: `echo "${a[*]}"` not `echo ${a[*]}` and `for elem in "${a[@]}"` not `for elem in ${a[@]}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From POSIX, [regarding `$*`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05):

> When the expansion occurs in a context where field splitting will not be performed, the initial fields shall be joined to form a single field with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the `IFS` variable if `IFS` contains at least one character, or separated by a `<space>` if `IFS` is unset, or with no separation if `IFS` is set to a null string.

To join words with a separator, you will have to use `$*`, or `${array[*]}` in `bash`:

```
$ set -- word1 word2 word3 "some other thing" word4
$ IFS='|'
$ echo "$*"
word1|word2|word3|some other thing|word4
```

Or, with an array in `bash`:

```
$ arr=( word1 word2 word3 "some other thing" word4 )
$ IFS='|'
$ echo "${arr[*]}"
word1|word2|word3|some other thing|word4
```

With your code:

```
$ myarr=( 1 2 3 )
$ echo "$( IFS="|"; echo "${myarr[*]}" )"
1|2|3
```

Answer (score 3):

Compare:

```
$ myarr=(1 2 3)
$ printf '%s\n' $( IFS="|"; echo "${myarr[@]}" )
1
2
3
$ printf '%s\n' $( IFS="|"; echo "${myarr[*]}" )
1|2|3
```

From man bash:

> @
> … When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, **"$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2"** ...
>
> *
> … When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with **the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable**. That is, **"$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c..."**, where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.

The description above is for positional parameters but it also apply to array expansions.